# $L^p_x$ norms of $f(x, x+y)$

Tags: lp-spaces, integral-inequality

> Let $f \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Then do there exists inequalities of the form $$\lVert f(x, A(x,y))\rVert_{L^p_x(\mathbb{R})} \lesssim_{A, p,q} \lVert f(x,y) \rVert_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^2)} $$ where $A : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R} $ is linear?

An often studied case is when $ f$ is separable: That is if $ f(x, y) = K(x) g(-y)$ then we have
$$  f(x , x -  y)  = K(x) g( y - x)\quad \text{ implying} $$ $$ \lVert  f (x, x - y)\rVert_{L^1_x} = \lVert  K(x) g(y - x ) \rVert_{L^1_x} =| K \star g(y)| \leq    \lVert  K \star g \rVert_{L^\infty} \leq \lVert  K \rVert_{L^2} \lVert  g \rVert_{L^2} = \lVert  f \rVert_{L^2}. 
$$
So are there similar results for some more general assumptions on $f?$

Comment: If $A(x, y)=ax+by$ then from the change of variable formula for integrals you see that what is relevant is $|b|$.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Apologies, I had phrased the question a little differently than what I wanted. I have edited it correctly now.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(x, y)=ax+by$. Up to a rotation and a dilation of $\mathbb R^2$ we can assume $a=1, b=0$. Thus, you are asking whether
$$\tag{1}
\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x, 0)|^p\, dx\right)^\frac1p\lesssim \left(\int_{\mathbb R^2} |f(x, y)|^q\, dxdy\right)^\frac1q.$$
As you mention in comments to this answer, this is not possible. Take $f\in L^q(\mathbb R^2)$. You can always rescale it as $f_\lambda(x, y)=f(x, \lambda y)$. The left-hand side of (1) is left unchanged, but the right-hand side is not, and you can make it arbitrarily small. Thus, (1) cannot hold with a constant that is independent on $f$.

---

In technical jargon you are asking whether an $L^q(\mathbb R^2)$ function can have an $L^p(\mathbb R)$ trace. This is not possible, as we just saw. You need to require more regularity on $f$, which will rule out the scaling counterexample. For more information on this subject, check https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_operator, or look up "Trace theorems" in your favorite book in PDE.

---

**PREVIOUS VERSION OF THIS ANSWER**. Here I erroneously refer to a conjectured inequality
$$\tag{2} \lVert f(x, A(x, y))\rVert_{L^p_{x, y}(\mathbb R^2)}\lesssim \lVert f \rVert_{L^q(\mathbb R^2)}.$$

Provided $b\ne 0$, the left-hand side of (2) is actually equivalent to $\lVert f \rVert_p$. Indeed, letting $(x', y')=(x, A(x, y))$ we see that $dx'dy'=|b|dxdy$, so
$$
\int_{\mathbb R^2} |f(x, A(x, y))|^p\, dxdy=\frac{1}{|b|} \int_{\mathbb R^2} |f(x', y')|\, dx'dy'.$$

Therefore, you are essentially asking whether $\lVert f\rVert_p\lesssim \lVert f\rVert_q$, which is only possible for arbitrary $f$ in the trivial case $p=q$.

Comment: Sorry, if it wasn't clear in the question but the norm is only on $x$. As such, I am more asking (for ex: $A(x,y) = x+ y$) 
$$\forall y \in \mathbb{R}:  \left( \int_{\mathbb{R} }   \lvert f(x, x + y) \rvert^p \mathrm{\,d} x \right)^{\frac{1}{p}} \lesssim C \left( \int_{\mathbb{R}^2}  \lvert f \rvert^q \mathrm{\,d} x \mathrm{\,d} y \right)^{\frac{1}{q}}
$$ 
But I now realise that this is fruitless as I can just mollify $\mathbf{1}_{(x, x + y)} $ given a fixed $y;$ then the right hand side can be made arbitrarily small for $ q = p$.

Comment: Oh sorry now I see. I had totally overlooked the $L^p_x$